# WPF - change text anchor in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Here's some XAML:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">  
    <Canvas Background="Beige">
        <Line X1="0" X2="200" Y1="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Line X1="100" X2="100" Y1="0" Y2="200" Stroke="Black"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            hello world1
            <LineBreak/>
            hello world2
            <LineBreak/>
            hello world3
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I want the text to appear in the top-right quadrant of my `Canvas` instead of the bottom right quadrant.

Is it possible to do in WPF?

Currently the text is drawn from topleft to bottomright, I would like it do be drawn from bottomleft to topright.

I couldn't find an answer on the internet that works inside a `Canvas`.

In my production code the text should be able to be of any length and height.

**Edit:**

I've been asked to provide a fully working sample, so here goes:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--The drawing area can be anything, a grid, a panel, a canvas... Can't just use specific alignment tools so I have to use a Transform-->
        <Grid x:Name="DrawingArea" Background="Beige" MouseMove="UIElement_OnMouseMove">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Margin="2">
                hello world1
                <LineBreak/>
                hello world2
                <LineBreak/>
                hello world3
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var mousePos = e.GetPosition(DrawingArea);
            TextBlock.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(mousePos.X, mousePos.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the text appears below the default Windows mouse cursor, I'd like it to appear above the default Windows mouse cursor.

Comment: So why don't you simply subtract the TextBlock's ActualHeight from mousePos.Y?

Comment: Currently I know the text height using codebehind, but in my actual application (MVVM based) I can't get the height of the text. So it'd need to somehow be subtracted from the `Transform` on the text with a ValueConverter or something. I got no clue on how to do that?

Comment: So the code in your question does again not show what you're actually doing. How do you expect to get any support here?

Comment: It shows exactly what I'm doing, moving a visual object using a `Transform`. It wouldn't be a short example representing my issue when I start adding things like `ItemsControl`s, `TemplateSelector`s, `DataTemplate`s and `DataBinding`s. I can add it all, but I doubt it'll add much extra to what I've already posted here.

Comment: As you say, you're translating a "visual object". Supposeded that it's a FrameworkElement, it always has an ActualHeight, which you could subtract from your cursor position.

Comment: I guess I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You see it in the lower right part because of the `TranslateTransform`. You set it to `X=100, Y=100`. If you set `Y=0` it should be on the top.

But you should consider some things with this code:

1. Why use `TranslateTransform` inside a canvas? You can just add the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties to the `TextBlock` and that should do it. Use the `TranslateTransform` only if you're looking to animate the element, and even then, it's more convenient to set it to (0, 0), and change it only during the animation.
2. Why are you using the canvas at all? And more over why inside a Grid? You should be able to achieve what you want by using a single Grid, or even a DockPanel. A Canvas is used only for graphics, that should always remain in the same place. There are better solutions for data, especially if it's supposed to change during runtime.

If you want a cross in the background of your grid, you can try something like this:

```
<Grid 
    Width="200" 
    Height="200" 
    Background="Beige">  
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Line 
        X1="0" 
        X2="200" 
        Y1="100" 
        Y2="100" 
        Stroke="Black" 
        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Line 
        X1="100" 
        X2="100" 
        Y1="0" 
        Y2="200" 
        Stroke="Black" 
        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1">
        hello world1
        <LineBreak/>
        hello world2
        <LineBreak/>
        hello world3
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am using a `Canvas`, with the `Translation` matrix, because that's what I'm working with (a CAD like situation). Using `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` is impossible for me, as the elements aren't inside a canvas (they are inside a `ContentPresenter`)

Answer (score -2):

Add a grid to your canvas and set the properties 
HorizontalAlignment="Right"
VerticalAlignment="Top"

```
<Canvas x:Name="newCanvas">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Hello World!"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    />
</Grid>
```